# How to implement simple validation in Scala

Tags: validation, scala, scalaz

Suppose I need to validate request parameters. The validation result is either `Success` or `Failure` with `NonEmptyList[String]`. I can probably use `ValidationNel[String, Unit]` but it seems a bit overkill. I guess I need a *simpler* abstraction (see below).

```
trait ValidationResult
object Success extends ValidationResult
class Failure(errors: NonEmptyList[String]) extends ValidationResult
```

and a binary operation `andAlso` to combine two results:

```
trait ValidationResult {
  def andAlso(other: ValidationResult): ValidationResult = 
    (this, other) match {
      case (Success, Success) => Success
      case (Success, failure @ Failure(_)) => failure
      case (failure @ Failure(_), Success) => failure
      case (Failure(errors1), Failure(errors2)) => Failure(errors1 + errors2) 
    } 
}
```

Now if I validate three parameters with functions `checkA`, `checkB`, and `checkC` I can easily compose them as follows:

```
def checkA(a: A): ValidationResult = ...
def checkB(b: B): ValidationResult = ...
def checkC(c: C): ValidationResult = ...
def checkABC(a: A, b: B, c: C) = checkA(a) andAlso checkB(b) andAlso checkC(c)
```

Does it make sense ?
Does this abstraction have a name ? Maybe a `Monoid` ?
Is it implemented in `scalaz` or any other scala library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a `Monoid`, and you can be much more precise : it is a `List[String]` (up to an isomporphism). `ValidationResult` is indeed isomorphic to a `List[String]`, with `Success` for `Nil`, and `andAlso` is concatenation `:::` / `++`.

This makes sense, a `ValidationResult` is a list of errors, and when there are none, that means success.

However, as you note right at the beginning, it all amounts to using `ValidationNel[String, Unit]`, where `Unit`, "no data of interest" is the interesting part. If means you will handle the actual data separately. You may win a little bit here, and that little bit is avoiding the syntax of `Applicative`, sprinkling your code with `|@|` and suchlike; also, a not-often mentioned price of Monads and Co, making it easier to work with a debugger. But there is a downside, as your code grows with places where errors may occur multiplying too, managing the flow by hand will quickly become painful and I would not go that way.

The usual alternative is exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to continue with the monoid because I need it just to validate output in my tests now.