# Example of simple validation with ValidationNel

Tags: validation, scala, scalaz

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925040/how-to-implement-simple-validation-in-scala):

Suppose I need to validate a data structure (e.g. XML, JSON, HttpRequest, etc.). I can define a validating function `A => ValidationNel[String, B]` and a wrapper class around it:

```
class Validate[A, B](run: A => ValidationNel[String, B]) {
  def apply(a: A) = run(a)
}
```

I add also methods `andThen` and `andAlso` to *compose* `Validates`:

```
def andThen[C](other: Validate[B, C]) = new Validate[A, C] {a =>
  this(a) flatMap (b => other(b))
}

def andAlso(other: Validate[A, B]) = new Validate[A, B] (a =>
  (this(a), other(a)) match {
     case ((Success(b), Success(b)) => Success(b)
     case (failure @ Failure(errors), Success(b)) => failure
     case (Success(b), failure @ Failure(errors)) => failure
     case (Failure(errors1), Failure(errors2)) => Failure(errors1 + errors2)
  }
)
```

Now I can validate a data structure as follows:

```
case class Header(...)
case class Payload(...)
case class Message(header: Header, payload: Payload)

val validateHeader: Validate[Header, Header] = ...

val validatePayload: Validate[Payload, Payload] = ...

type ValidateMessage = Validate[Message, Message]

val validateMessageHeader =
  new ValidateMessage(m => validateHeader(m.header); m)

val validateMessagePayload =
  new ValidateMessage(m => validatePayload(m.payload); m)

val validateMessage = validateMessageHeader andAlso validateMessagePayload
```

Does it make sense ? How would you suggest fix/improve it ?

Comment: Three notes: 1. `ValidationNel[String, A]` doesn't have a semigroup instance unless `A` does, so I don't understand what's going on in your `andAlso`. 2. Using `flatMap` on `Validation` is a pretty strong indication that you should consider `\/` instead. 3. Your `Validate` is isomorphic to `Kleisli[({ type L[x] = ValidationNel[String, x] })#L, A, B]`, and using that would give you a semigroup instance for free when `B` has a semigroup.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback ! (1) I will fix `andAlso` in the question (2) Hmm (3) You are right. I will try it.

Comment: @TravisBrown `Kleisli[M[_], A, B]` is a semigroup iff `M[B]` is a semigroup, is it correct ?

Comment: Ah, right—I misspoke when I said you only need a semigroup for `B`.

Comment: This question isn't clear. You ask how we might fix or improve it. If it needs to be fixed, what is wrong with it? If this works but you want improvement, then this is probably off topic and should go to codereview.se